# Java method for updating money with cents over 99

Tags: java

I am trying to create a method so that if the user enters a number of cents over 99, the updateMoney method will add dollars accordingly and then place the extra change once the cents goes under 100.

```
public void updateMoney(int cent) {
        int addDollars = 0;
        int change = 0;
        if (cent > 99) {
            for(int i = cent; i > 99; i -= 100)
            {
                
                addDollars += 1;
                cent -= 100;
            }           
            
        }
        this.dollars = dollars + addDollars;
        this.cents = cent;
        
    }

public Money(int dol, int cent) {
        if (cent < 0 || dol < 0) {
            System.out.println("Invalid amount entered");
        } else {
            
            if (cent > 99) {
                updateMoney(cent);
                    
            }
        
        this.dollars = dol;
        this.cents = cent;
        }
    }
```

This is the code I am currently working with.

I had originally tried a different method that ended up not working so I tried doing something like this instead but my outputs are still off.
In my driver I ran
Money money = new Money(15, 300); and the output was $15.00 when it should end up being $18.99

Comment: This may not be the only issue, but `dollars += cents / 100;` will work, then just `cents = cents % 100;`  But I think there's error in other places in the code you haven't shown us.

Comment: public Money(int dol, int cent) {
  if (cent < 0 || dol < 0) {
   System.out.println("Invalid amount entered");
  } else {
   
   if (cent > 99) {
    updateMoney(cent);
     
   }
  
  this.dollars = dol;
  this.cents = cent;
  }
 }. This was the constructor I created when creating the money object

Comment: You never account for the initial `this.cents` value; your loop only factors in the new `cent`. So whether you have `(15, 300)` initially or `(15, 0)`, your code will work exactly the same.

Comment: 1. Please edit your question and add the code there, the formatting in a comment is terrible. 2. This part `this.dollars = dol;` needs to be `+=` or the previous dollar amount get erased.

Comment: An aside: for something like `println("Invalid amount` it's not good to find an invalid value and then allow execution to proceed.  Instead you should probably throw an `new IllegalArgumentException( "Invalid..." );` with the same string message.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider storing your dollars and cents in one long value. The following code takes your dollars and cents, combines them, adds the user's inputted cents correctly, and splits them up in dollars and cents again. But why not just keep them together all the time?

```
long dollarsWithCents = dollars * 100 + cents;
dollarsWithCents += parsedUserInput;
cents = dollarsWithCents % 100;
dollars = dollarsWithCents / 100;
```